# Get data from SQL Server using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get data from SQL server using JQuery, I followed following example to do so: [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-retrieve-data-from-database-in-asp-net-web-api-using-jquery/). But I am getting not found error when I am trying to retrieve data.
1. I added EF which generated Context.cs file with my table's column names.
2. Created API controller:

```
    public class GPSController : ApiController
    {
       public HttpResponseMessage Get()
       {
          List<gps> gpsList = new List<gps>();
          using (DBModel dc = new DBModel())
          {
             gpsList = dc.gps.OrderBy(a => a.car_id).ToList();
             HttpResponseMessage response;
             response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, gpsList);
             return response;
          }
       }
    }
```

3. Crated Home controller:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       // GET: Home
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View();
       }
   }
   ```
4. My Index.cshtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/GetData.js"></script>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-4">
        <h5 class="text-center">HOW TO RETRIEVE DATA FROM DATABASE IN THE ASP.NET Web API USING JQUERY</h5>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-primary text-uppercase text-white">
                <h5 class="card-title">Employee List</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <button id="btnGetData" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0">Load Employee List</button>
            </div>
            <div id="updatePanel" style="padding:20px;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

5. Script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:xxxxx/";
    $('#btnGetData').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: apiBaseUrl + 'api/gps',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var $table = $('<table/>').addClass('dataTable table table-bordered table-striped');
                var $header = $('<thead/>').html('<tr><th>gps_id</th><th>device_id</th><th>car_id</th><th>long</th><th>lat</th><th>speed</th><th>time_log</th></tr>');
                $table.append($header);
                $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                    var $row = $('<tr/>');
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.gps_id));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.device_id));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.car_id));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.long));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.lat));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.speed));
                    $row.append($('<td/>').html(val.time_log));
                    $table.append($row);
                });
                $('#updatePanel').html($table);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

6. Added connection string to web config.
What am I doing wrong, could you please help me. Thanks.

Comment: what not found? please post complete error message

Comment: Did you tried to add a breakpoint at the api controller? Did you get the error alert from the ajax? Your question does not describe what is the problem that you are facing

Comment: Can you access `http://localhost:xxxxx/api/gps` directly?  I can't remember but  could it be case sensitive (GPS instead)...